# Show $ \left| \frac {xy}{x^2-xy+y^2} \right|\le 1 , \forall (x,y) \neq (0,0).$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value, solution-verification

My approach:
$$ \left| \frac {xy}{x^2-xy+y^2} \right|= \frac {\lvert xy \rvert}{\lvert (x-y)^2+xy\rvert}\leq \frac {\lvert {xy} \rvert}{\lvert {xy} \rvert} = 1$$

Is this right?

If yes, how do we know that $\lvert (x-y)^2 +xy\rvert \geq \lvert xy\rvert$ ?

Comment: This's wrong! How do you know whether $xy>0$?

Comment: Hint: $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$. This's all you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align}
 x^2+y^2\geq 0 &\text{ and } (x-y)^2\geq 0\\
\implies x^2+y^2-xy\geq -xy &\text{ and } (x-y)^2+xy\geq xy\\
\implies x^2+y^2-xy\geq -xy &\text{ and } x^2+y^2-xy\geq xy\\
\implies x^2+y^2-xy\geq |xy|\\
\implies |x^2+y^2-xy|\geq |xy|
\end{align}

Comment: How do you go from $x^2 + y^2 -xy \geq -xy$ to $x^2 + y^2 -xy \geq |xy|$?

Comment: $x^2+y^2-xy\geq$ both $-xy$ and $xy$. Thus, it is $\geq |xy|$.

Comment: Okay. I didn't get it at first.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following reasoning a bit of better.

If $xy=0$ so it's obvious.

But for $xy\neq0$ we obtain: $$\left|\frac{xy}{x^2-xy+y^2}\right|=\frac{|xy|}{x^2-xy+y^2}\leq\frac{|xy|}{x^2-|xy|+y^2}=\frac{|xy|}{(|x|-|y|)^2+|xy|}\leq\frac{|xy|}{|xy|}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $2|xy|\leq x^2+y^2$ which follows from AM-GM (or you can verify it directly by considering $|xy|=\pm xy$). Note that the denominator is positive for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$. So
$$\left|\frac{xy}{x^2-xy+y^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-xy+y^2} $$
and now you have to show
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-xy+y^2}\leq 1 \Leftrightarrow \\
\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-xy+y^2}\leq 2 \Leftrightarrow \\
0\leq x^2-2xy+y^2 $$
which is true. Equality is reached only if $x=y$.